# How to Create A new table from another database in current database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have 2 databases names as 'Employee' in that it one table 'users' and 2nd database is 'customer' i want to import all data from **employee->users table** to **customer->cust_users** table using codeigniter . How can i do it?? 
customer db will be main DB
i have a query

```
"Create TABLE mytest AS (SELECT * FROM user)"
```

I Have added config like ->

**main db  this will main customer db**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'customer';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

**user database config 2nd Emp db**

```
$db['emp']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['Emp']['username'] = 'root';
$db['emp']['password'] = '';
$db['emp']['database'] = 'employee';
$db['emp']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['emp']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['empr']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['emp']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['emp']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['emp']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['emp']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['emp']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['emp']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['emp']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['emp']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$this->load->database();
$users_db=$this->load->database('emp', TRUE);
$this->db->query("Create TABLE cust_users AS (SELECT * FROM employee)");
```

But this create a table in employee  db  not in customer db . How should i create table in customer db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could point which db you want to create by adding it explicitly:

```
$this->db->query("CREATE TABLE customer_db.cust_users AS (SELECT * FROM employee)");
```